# How to get facebook friends details of logined user in my site?

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to fetch the facebook friends details such as name, photo,current working and joined date. Am using PHP. I am tried to use the codes which are given in facebook-developer site.Url of that site is as followes.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

And i have completed the login code now i wants to display the friends details in my site as it is in the following url...

http://www.jobisjob.com/MyNetwork

In that please follow the facebook login link...

Can any one tell me how to do that using php?.

Comment: i think you you cant get the friend detail ...

Comment: @Mayankswami Then how they got in jobisjob.com?. There they categorized the friends and current job right?. Can you please tell me how they categorizing that?.

Comment: no i think the don't provide this you can check this on facebook apps the simple method is to login with facebook apps and than you will know what the facebook provide ....and there i never found about friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you request the proper permissions for this (look at the friends permissions column) - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/. Of course, getting this data depends on their privacy settings as well, so you should be able to handle both situations when this data is provided and when not.